# How do you perform get_or_create on DRF ModelViewSet when over riding create()?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a ModelViewSet with create() method overwritten as I may be creating more than one instance at a time. I was wondering if it is possible to perform a get_or_create instead of .perform_create() as seen below?

Essentially if I make the same call twice I would only like the first call to create the instance/s.

```
class CreateTokenView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = BayAccessToken.objects.all()
    serializer_class = accessTokenSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
```

Or is the best option to just loop through and perform own get_or_create on data?

Answer (score 1):

You have to override the create method on the serializer, something like this:

```
class accessTokenSerializer(serializer.X):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return YourModel.objects.get_or_create(name=validated_data.pop("name"), defaults=validated_data)[0]
```